# Magento 2: Get Related products from Product Id now showing Name and price

Tags: magento2, related-products

Below is my code to get related products from products id, It is working fine but not giving values for name and price it just gives SKU and id

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($lastid);

    $relatedProducts = $product->getRelatedProducts();

    if (!empty($relatedProducts)) {
        echo 'Related Products <br />';   
        foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
            echo $relatedProduct->getId().'-->'.$relatedProduct->getPrice().'-->'.$relatedProduct->getName().'-->'.$relatedProduct->getId(); //get name
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you are getting when `var_dump($relatedProducts);`  ?

Comment: where do you want to show this related products ?

Comment: on checkout success.phtml

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a better solution, But for now you need to load product in loop, Which will give you all the data of product.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($lastid);

$relatedProducts = $product->getRelatedProducts();

//var_dump($relatedProducts);

if (!empty($relatedProducts)) {
    echo 'Related Products <br />';   
    foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($relatedProduct->getId());
        echo $relatedProduct->getId().'-->'.$_product->getPrice().'-->'.$_product->getName().'-->'.$relatedProduct->getId(); //get name
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This was really slow in my case (I have lots of related products). Karpa's solution is much faster, you just have to specify each field you want loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can (should) avoid load each product in the loop. You can add the desired attributes in the collection and then use them in your loop.

```
$relatedProducts = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('color', 'name');

foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
    // echo $relatedProduct->getSku();  
    echo $relatedProduct->getName(); //get name
    echo $relatedProduct->getData('color'); //or getColor()
    // echo print_r($relatedProduct->getData(), true); //Show all attributes      
}
```